# state synchronization in software architecture

Tags: architecture, software-design

I am reading book on software architecture in practice. Here for availability quality attribute authors has mentioned a below

State resynchronization is a reintroduction partner to the active redundancy
and passive redundancy. When used along side the active redundancy tactic the state resynchronization occurs organically (i.e., step by step), because the active and standby components each receive and process identical inputs in parallel. In practice, the states of the active and standby components are periodically compared to ensure synchronization. This comparison may be based on a CRC or, for systems providing safety critical services, a message digest calculation ( a one-way hash function).

A special case of tactic is found in stateless services, whereby any resource can handle a request from another
(failed) resource

1. what does author mean by "A special case of tactic is ound in stateless services, whereby any resource can handle a request from another
   (failed) resource"

Comment: Can you properly format quote (you [must](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299918/1997232) attribute it) and question?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the last statement :

When the services do not preserve state between requests, then no state resynchronization is required, and therefore a request that was sent to an instance of the service that is in a failed state, can simply be forwarded to another instance of the service.